# How to find minimum from an array in Octave?

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave, minimum

I am a complete beginner at Octave!
I am struggling to figure out the minimum value from the array mse_array. I keep getting an error saying: "subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals"

Could someone help me? Here's my code:

```
function randomLines(data1, data2)
mse_array = []
A = rand(2,10)*100
 for i = columns(A)
    max = A (1, i) 
    min = A (2, i)
    m = (max-min)/0.16
    p = [m min];
    array_function_values = polyval(p,data2);
    current_mse = mseFunction(data1,array_function_values);
    mse_array(end + 1) = current_mse
 endfor
min_value = min(mse_array)
endfunction
```

Comment: In which line are you getting the error ?

Comment: Please provide the full error message. Also, please specify what `mseFunction` is and example inputs to your function `randomLines` that generate the error so that we can replicate it ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things wrong with your code. Here are a few to get you started.

The error is probably occurring at this line:

```
min_value = min(mse_array)
```

You're using `mse_array` as an index into `min`, but the values in `mse_array` are likely to valid array indices as the error states. (I'm guessing at this purely based on the name of the variable, `mse_array`, which appear to be from some form of mean squared error calculation.) It's important to check the line number and everything else in error messages.

Another issue in that your `for` loop only evaluates once. The [`columns`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Object-Sizes.html#XREFcolumns) function will return the scalar number of columns of `A`. Thus your your loop declaration is equivalent to:

```
for i = 10
```

In other words, the code will only look at the last column of `A`. You probably want to use:

```
for i = 1:columns(A)
```

Lastly, it's a bad idea to overwrite the built-in [`min`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Utility-Functions.html#XREFmin) and [`max`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Utility-Functions.html#XREFmax) functions in Octave with your own variable names. If you overwrite the built-in `min` function, you won't be able to use it anymore directly until you call `clear min` (alternatively, you can call [`builtin`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Overloading-and-Autoloading.html), but you should avoid that). Instead, just choose better variable names.

Comment: It's the "lastly"-part that is most important. The OP appears to intend using `min` as a function in the `min_value`-line.

Comment: @Jonas: Possibly. The `min` function has already been overloaded in the `for` loop above. It's not necessary to change the name of the variable for this code to "work".

Answer (score 2):

### Q: How to find a minimum from an array in Octave?

**`octave`** has built-in self-describing documentation to use once in doubts

### A: Always re-read both **`help min`** and **`doc min`**

```
octave-3.2.4.exe:1> help min
`min' is a function from the file C:\Octave\3.2.4_gcc-4.4.0\libexec\octave\3.2.4\oct\i686-pc-mingw32\max.oct

 -- Loadable Function:  min (X)
 -- Loadable Function:  min (X, Y)
 -- Loadable Function:  min (X, Y, DIM)
 -- Loadable Function: [W, IW] = min (X)
     For a vector argument, return the minimum value.  For a matrix
     argument, return the minimum value from each column, as a row
     vector, or over the dimension DIM if defined.  For two matrices
     (or a matrix and scalar), return the pair-wise minimum.  Thus,

          min (min (X))

     returns the smallest element of X, and

          min (2:5, pi)
             =>  2.0000  3.0000  3.1416  3.1416
     compares each element of the range `2:5' with `pi', and returns a
     row vector of the minimum values.

     For complex arguments, the magnitude of the elements are used for
     comparison.

     If called with one input and two output arguments, `min' also
     returns the first index of the minimum value(s).  Thus,

          [x, ix] = min ([1, 3, 0, 2, 0])
             =>  x = 0
                 ix = 3

     See also: max, cummin, cummax
```

Re-defining (thus rendering un-usable) elements as reserved words just increases troubles. Try to use your own naming convention, that will not harm the rest of the system -- i.e. **`anArrayMinimumVALUE`** or **`aSmallestVALUE`**, rather than "killing" the Octave function **`min()`** by creating a variable named by accident as "also" `min`